# For each non-missing element of first vector, compare with lagging elements of second vector

Tags: r

I am sure my solution (see "desired result") is massively overcomplicating the problem. I've got two vectors - vector 1 for start, vector 2 for the end of a measure. NA for no change recorded.

I want to check for weird data entries - i.e., something ends which has not started. I only want the plausible data entries. A measure can end at the same time when the next measure starts (e.g., see measure "C" in the example).

My approach:
I am using cumsum to create cuts for each new non-missing element in the start vector, and for each cut checking if there are more than one "end" entry, and removing NAs when there are non-NA entries.
The idea is to get a vector with either a unique end value or NA, and I can compare this with the unique elements of the start vector. The resulting logical vector is used to subset the start list.

Additional, possibly relevant information:
The two vectors are actually columns of a data frame. Any package welcome.

Also, if you have a suggestion for a better question title, I'd love to hear it. Cheers.

```r
start_r <- c("A", NA, NA, "B", NA, NA, "C", NA, NA, "D", NA, "D")
end_r   <- c(NA, "A", NA, NA, "B", "C", NA, NA, NA, "C", NA, NA)

## as suggested by Henrik, here as data frame. 
## "B" has two following entries in column "end_r" and is therefore not plausible
data.frame(start_r, end_r)
#>    start_r end_r
#> 1        A  <NA>
#> 2     <NA>     A
#> 3     <NA>  <NA>
#> 4        B  <NA>
#> 5     <NA>     B
#> 6     <NA>     C
#> 7        C  <NA>
#> 8     <NA>  <NA>
#> 9     <NA>  <NA>
#> 10       D     C
#> 11    <NA>  <NA>
#> 12       D  <NA>

end_lag <- dplyr::lead(end_r)
cs1 <- cumsum(!is.na(start_r))

ls_start <- split(start_r, cs1)

ls_end_lagged <- split(end_lag, cs1)
ls_end_nona <- lapply(ls_end_lagged, 
                        function(x) if(all(is.na(unique(x)))) NA 
                                      else if (length(unique(x[!is.na(x)])) >1) NA
                                        else x[!is.na(x)]
                      )

v_start <- sapply(split(start_r, cs1), function(x) x[!is.na(x)])
v2 <- sapply(ls_end_nona, function(x) x[1])

## desired result
data.frame(start_r = unname(unlist(ls_start[v_start %in% v2])))
#>   start_r
#> 1       A
#> 2    <NA>
#> 3    <NA>
#> 4       C
#> 5    <NA>
#> 6    <NA>
```

Comment: What's wrong with value B?

Comment: @arg0naut91 double "end" entry

Comment: @Henrik thanks for the suggestion. I will post the data frame. B is not correct, because the following "end" has two entries. So there is a "C" which either is a wrong entry, or "C" has been not entered in "start" when it should have been.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'v1' can also be created with

```
v1 <- tapply(start_r, cs1, na.omit)
```

and for the other case

```
library(dplyr)
v2 <- stack(ls_end_lagged) %>%
      group_by(ind) %>%
      summarise(values = 
    if(all(is.na(values))| n_distinct(na.omit(values)) > 1 ) NA else 
       first(na.omit(values)) ) %>% 
    pull(values)
```

-checking the output

```
unlist(ls_start[v1 %in% v2], use.names = FALSE)
#[1] "A" NA  NA  "C" NA  NA
```

---

Or another option is to do this all with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
tibble(start = start_r, end = lead(end_r)) %>%
    group_by(grp = cumsum(!is.na(start))) %>%
    summarise(across(everything(), ~
        if(all(is.na(.)) | n_distinct(na.omit(.)) > 1) NA_character_ 
         else first(na.omit(.))), .groups = 'drop') %>%
    select(-grp)
```